# Big Query equivalent of USE statement

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to do what the USE statement does in SQL?
All the examples I have seen follow the format project:dataset.table, or sometimes just dataset.table .

I'm hoping to be able to USE dataset or USE project:dataset then just specify the table name in the SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this in SQL. But at the API level, you can specify the `defaultDataset` config option to get the same effect.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.defaultDataset